# Ler um número digitado (R)

Tags: r

Bom dia a todos, preciso fazer um script barbadinha em R onde tenho que ler um número digitado e dar o antecessor dele (tipo, se eu escrever 10 o antecessor é 9).

Mas eu tenho um problema que eu não sei como faz o começo...

```
print("Digite um numero")
//O QUE VAI AQUI PARA LER O NUMERO DIGITADO
nAntecessor= numero-1
print("O antecessor é:", nAntecessor)
```

Estou usando o programa do R Project...

Comment: Talvez `numero <- scan()`.

Comment: e o que vai dentro dos parenteses do scan?

Comment: Nada! Tente e veja. Para terminar a entrada de dados numéricos, digite <Enter> sem dar entrada a um novo número.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, coloque sua solução nas respostas, assim ajuda a ver que a pergunta já foi resolvida.

Comment: OK, acho um pouco demais, mas é de fato capaz de ser melhor.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é muito simples, basta usar `scan` sem qualquer argumento.

```
print("Digite um numero")
numero <- scan()
nAntecessor <- numero - 1
cat("O antecessor é: ", nAntecessor, "\n")
```

Note-se que mudei o `print` para `cat`. Como estava *não* resultava uma vez que `print` só usa um argumento. Para usá-lo teria que ser

```
print(paste("O antecessor é: ", nAntecessor))
```